# Firebase Performance configuration fails with v1.1.2 when using implementation or api

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, firebase-performance

I'm trying to upgrade my `firebase-plugins` dependency version to `1.1.2` which supports the Android Gradle Plugin version `3+`, but the Gradle build configuration keeps failing unless I use `compile` which is deprecated. I'm using Play Services version `11.4.2` and and I have the `firebase-perf` dependency added like so which fails:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$playServicesVersion"
```

The only way to fix it is to change the above `implementation` to `compile`. Has anyone found a solution to get around this? (Aside from downgrading to `firebase-plugins` version `1.1.0-alpha1`?)

Here's the error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> To use the Firebase Performance Plugin, the Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK must be added to the app's build.gradle. Please add compile 'com.google.firebase:f
irebase-perf:VERSION_NUMBER_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_11.0.4' to the app's build.gradle.
```

**Edit:** this has been fixed in `firebase-plugins:1.1.3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is because firebase-perf plugin is specifically looking for the presence of 'compile' configuration for com.google.firebase:firebase-perf SDK. If the SDK is not included in build.gradle at build time, there will be a run time crash later.

Android Studio 3.0 replaces 'compile' with 'implementation', the plugin code should instead checking 'implementation' configuration for firebase-perf SDK.

The workaround now is to continue using: 
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$playServicesVersion"

This will be fixed in the future firebase-plugins release.

Comment: Cool, are you a Firebase dev? If so, do you have an approximate ETA?

Comment: Please use firebase-plugins version 1.1.3 and you can use 'implementation' now.